# Array values in state of functional component not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have setup a useState hook as follows.

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      qty: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      qty: 0,
    }
  ]);
```

I have a TouchOpacity component which fires the following function when pressed.

```
 const _onPress = () => {
    const productArr = products;
    productArr[0].qty = value;
    setProducts(productArr);
  };
```

The expected outcome is that product with id 1 must increase the qty to 1, however this does not happen.

When i use the spread operator for the products from state as follows it works as expected.

```
 const _onPress = () => {
    const productArr = [...products];
    productArr[0].qty = value;
    setProducts(productArr);
  };
```

What is the reason for this ?

Comment: With your first code block you attempt to mutate state directly (which is not recommended to do and won't trigger re-render). Second block does shallow copy of state array and properly assigns modified version of that array to `products`

Comment: Why is `const productArr = products;` not considered as copying an array ? I am creating a new variable right ?

Comment: @Muljayan it's called copying the reference.

Comment: Got it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Note that even with the spread operator, in both of your examples, you are mutating the state.

If you need to use arrays inside your state or nested structures, I would highly recommend trying a library such as `immer` which will simplify things, is more efficient than recreating objects, and overall will give you a very good sense of notion of not mutating the state:

```js
import produce from "immer";

const [products, setProducts] = useState([
  {
    id: 1,
    qty: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    qty: 0,
  }
]);

const _onPress = () => {
  setProducts(
    produce(products, draft => draft[0].qty = value)
  );
}
```